# error 1064: showing syntax error not able to find whatss causing this error

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

code:

```
 def delete_data(self):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="Satpute@223", database="stm")
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE roll_no=%s",self.Roll_No_var.get())
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    self.fetch_data()
    self.clear()

def search_data(self):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="Satpute@223", database="stm")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from students where"+str(self.search_by.get())+" like '%"+str(self.search_text.get())+"%'")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    if len(rows) != 0:
        self.Student_table.delete(*self.Student_table.get_children())
        for row in rows:
            self.Student_table.insert('', END, values=row)

        con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: There should be a space after `where` word in the SQL inside `search_data()`.

Comment: Never use `cur.execute("string_expression")` - always use `sql_text = "string_expression"` and then `cur.execute(sql_text)`. Thiss allows to print `sql_text` variable value and check SQL for errors.

Comment: Please *do not* use string formatting or concatenation to prepare queries. These are prone to injection attacks. Use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE roll_no=%s",
(
    self.Roll_No_var.get(),      # seperate your entries from the sql
))                               # code

--------

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE example=%s LIKE %s ORDER BY ....",
(
     '%' + self.your_entries.get() + '%',     # there are different ways for mysql
     '%' + self.your_entries.get() + '%',     # make sure, that your table, you created matched, with your entries.
                                              #or you will get this mysql.errors
))
```

Comment: That is always more useful to add explanations about how the provided code answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: yes, but I saw that acw1668 postet before while I was writing, so I posted another way. But you`'re right, i edit

Comment: @JoeMo Your answer is better than the other answer here, but you lack explanation. Other answer is prone to SQL injections as I have said before.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `delete_data()`, the second argument of `cur.execute(...)` should be a tuple or list:

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE roll_no=%s", (self.Roll_No_var.get(),))
```

There should be a space after the `where` word in the SQL statement inside `search_data()` function:

```py
"select * from students where "+str(self.search_by.get())+" like '%"+str(self.search_text.get())+"%'"
```

Using *f-string* is more readable:

```
sql = f"SELECT * FROM students WHERE {self.search_by.get()} LIKE %s"
cur.execute(sql, (f"%{self.search_text.get()}%",))
```

Comment: Your queries are prone to SQL injection

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks for the remind.  But I still cannot find a proper way to specify the field name as it cannot use placeholder for field name.  Would you mine advise how to do it?

Comment: It is true, fieldnames cannot be used as placeholders, instead whitelisting on the input of fieldname is done, here it seems fine now :D